# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $sql (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, android, json

hoping for some help here... currently i am trying to figure out what's wrong with these codes, i am stuck here for 2 days, really appreciate any kind of help. i can't seem to detect my mistake, hope for sharp eyes here.

am passing variables from android apps to php, in return the php script should return "success" or "fail"..

but i got the above error on line 6, i do not understand why. hoping someone to point out my mistake. thanks a trillion...

```
<?php
define('HOST','myserver.mysql');
define('USER','myserver_user');
define('PASS','myserver_pass');
define('DB','myserver_db');  

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

$mobile1 = $_POST['mobile1'];
$imei1 = $_POST['imei1'];
    
$sql = "select status from phone where mobile1='$mobile1' and imei1='$imei1'";
 
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
if(isset($check)){
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

please point out my mistake, please... thanks.

this is the line that was pointed to.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

thanks.

Comment: You should post the real code and the real error message; line 8 is blank. Are you sure this is the right script? And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: noted the sql injection problem, i removed comment/note i've made. let me re-edit the post. thanks.

Comment: Line 6 is also blank...

Comment: question edited, should be line-6 now. i don't understand what's wrong with that line. by the way, sql running php ver 5.3

Comment: this is the problem line -> $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

Comment: Is everything good with the credentials you provide? is DB accessible?

Comment: yup, DB is accessible... other script running in the same folder is working just fine, only this script... that' s why i'm stuck...  i am trying all possible solution, looking at all angle now. thanks mate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i managed to solve it and just want to share my answer with you guys.

hopefully this post will serves as a lesson to others as well.

what actually happened was there are "invisible" spaces between the codes, most probably when i copied from somewhere. "invisible codes" means something you get like [alt]+255 on numeric keyboard. these invisible characters was read by the php codes, thus returning the error.

the point is, ALWAYS CHECK FOR EMPTY SPACES OR UNUSED SPACES, delete all the unnecessary spaces. it might fix your (mine) problem.

thanks guys... took me 2 days... long days.

thanks stackoverflow.com

ps: hope moderator will keep this post open, as the answer might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe work with this?

`$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","USER","PASS","DB");`

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: there are several others php scripts that use the same code (the defining of db host etc, including $con)... only this particular php gives me headache...

Comment: I do not understand what you mean ?
do you use mysql?

Comment: there are two variable define. that's to make a problem in line 2-5

Comment: as said, those 2-5 lines are identical to some other php which i am using. (noted the sql injection part)

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect('HOST','USER','PASS','DB') or die('Unable to Connect');

try this way, have a problem again?

Comment: i was testing your answer just now, as you've shown above. same error, but this time it jumps to line that starts with "$sql"... that's the line with sql statement. strange right ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is caused by spaces in some of the lines that you may think they are empty but it's not. remove those space characters and the error will be gone.